# cant use laravel response on extended controllers

Tags: php, laravel, response

im using laravel and i want to put **response()->json()** in a method on laravel's controller and calls it from extended controllers or make a **__destruct** method and put **return response()->json()** in it?
this is my code in controller :

```
class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    protected function prepare_response(int $http_code , string $message , array $data) : array
    {
        return response()->json(['http_code' => $http_code,'message'=>$message,'data'=>$data]);
    }

}
```

sample of my calling :

```
class PersonsController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->prepare_response(200,'successfully_created',[]);
    }
}
```

why this code is not work and response on my postman is empty line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't returning the json in the extended controller, try this.

```
class PersonsController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->prepare_response(200,'successfully_created',[]);
    }
}
```

You return the json *to* your extended controller, but that never returns it.

Answer (score 2):

You miss **return**

```php
class PersonsController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->prepare_response(200,'successfully_created',[]);
    }
}
```